# Use pm-hibernate instead of systemctl hibernate

Tags: power-management, systemd, hibernate

I followed archwiki's wiki page to set up hibernation on my laptop, and it works great if I call `pm-hibernate`, but it just locks the screen, reconnects to wifi, and clears my clipboard if I call `systemctl hibernate`.

I tried editing the hibernate service (`sudo systemctl edit systemd-hibernate.service`) to

```
[Unit]
Description=Hibernate
Documentation=man:systemd-suspend.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pm-hibernate
```

and reload the daemon (I even tried rebooting) but that doesn't work either. Also, there's nothing in `journalctl -b -u systemd-hibernate.service`.

I've been at this for 3 days. Any help would be appreciated. Even stupid ideas like monitoring a log file (via a script) and calling `pm-hibernate` when something gets logged.

Comment: having problems (again) with hibernate myself , so 'man systemd-hibernate.service' is useful to know about. nothing in that log for me either. and no errors on journalctl | grep hibernate . tried pm-hibernate again, worked this time, it just takes 5 min to store the 12Gb. blinking cursor top left while-U-wait.

Comment: why don't use just use pm-hibernate if it works... set a hotkey to it.